# jsPlumb.fire("jsPlumbDemoLoaded", instance); what is this?

Tags: jsplumb

When reading the demo code of jsPlumb, I saw this statement is called in several demos.

```
jsPlumb.fire("jsPlumbDemoLoaded", instance);
```

However I could not find the API for jsPlumb.fire(). And I don't know where the first parameter is defined.

Could anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same statement had me a little confused too.

It seems to be calling an undocumented [`EventGenerator`](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/apidocs/classes/jsPlumbUtil.EventGenerator.html) method.
The first argument is the name of an event. The only event that seems to be set up by default is "ready".
So the `fire` method checks if an event called "jsPlumbDemoLoaded" exists, then, when it's not found, the method returns.

My guess is it's a leftover from an older version.